# Javascript | Que al arrancar la página, el input este en FOCUS para escribir sin clicar

Tags: javascript

No consigo que al arrancar la página, el focus esté dentro del input para se pueda escribir en él sin tener que clicar antes dentro de él. ¿Qué sucede?

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.theFormID.theFieldID.focus();
</script>
```

Html:

```
<form id="theFormID" method="get" action="">
    <input id="theFieldID" type="text"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Los elementos `input` tienen un atributo llamado [`autofocus`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp) que hace precisamente lo que requieres.

```
<form id="theFormID" method="get" action="">
    <input id="theFieldID" type="text" autofocus/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

De este modo te evitas tener que tratarlo des del *script*.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Perfecto. Muchas gracias VRoxa.

Answer (score 0):

Comentarios:

- El botón debe tener declaración como `input`, ya que lo tienes como `button` pero la misma requiere tanto la etiqueta de apertura como la de cierre
- Necesitas asignar la funcionalidad deseada a un evento por ejemplo cuando el [documento esté cargado](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)
- Asignas el `input` a una variable
- Cuando el documento haya *cargado* pasas al cuerpo de la función la variable anteriormente declarada que nos sirve para acceder al `input`
- a dicha variable le das acceso al método `focus()`

Entonces cuando el documento esté cargado en su totalidad, el `input` quedará con un *focus* en él.

Código:

```html
    <form id="theFormID" method="get" action="">
        <input id="theFieldID" type="text"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
    <script>
      let caja = document.getElementById("theFieldID")
      
      window.addEventListener("load", () => {
        caja.focus()
      })
    </script>
```

Comment: Parece que con autofocus se soluciona. Pero muchas gracias por la respuesta BetaM.

Comment: Adelante @julian lo que mas te convenga, aqui solo esta otra opción